# WP8.1 SL Xap couldn't be detected on WP8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, xap

I create a windowsphone silverlight app package -> Blah.Xap

Then I place it in my phone.

In theory,

in 'MainMenu'->'Store'->'...'

there should be an option like:

'Install local apps'

But it didn't show up.

That option shows up when I place *.appx (WRT) file in the phone.

So is there anything setting I should set when build the *.xap from VS studio?

Thanks very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can only install apps downloaded from Store in that way. If your XAP is not from Store i.e. built using Visual Studio then it won't show up.

Comment: so how do I 'publish' a Xap to store?
I find tons of articles, but most of them are about storeApp, not xap file....

Comment: Both XAP and APPX packages can be submitted in same way. Check this link: [Submit your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206724%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)